# Empty EntityManager QueryBuilder error

Tags: php, symfony, entity, formbuilder

I'm building a form in Symfony 2. I'm updating a website where I found it nessesary that I made a new:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options){
```

in a new file.

Now I duplicated an existing formbuilder file that works.(Ofcours I changed the parameters and values).
This is what the public formbuilder function looks like:

SerialNumberType.php

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options){
    $query = $this->em->createQueryBuilder();
    $query->select('*')
        ->from('AppBundle:SerialNumber', 'sn');

    $serialnumbers = $query->getQuery()->getResult();

    $options = array();
    foreach($serialnumbers as $serialnumber){
        $options[$serialnumber['id']] = $serialnumber['id'];
        $options[$serialnumber['product_revision_id']] = $serialnumber['product_revision_id'];
        $options[$serialnumber['booking_id']] = $serialnumber['booking_id'];
        $options[$serialnumber['serial_nr']] = $serialnumber['serial_nr'];
    }

    $builder->add("serial_nr", "text", array("label" => "Serienummer"));
}
```

em is created above the formbuilder and looks like this:

```
/**
 * @var EntityManager $em
 */
protected $em;

public function __construct($em) {
    $this->em = $em;
}
```

I did use this to:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
```

Now when I tried to request the function `buildForm` I got this error:

```
Error: Call to a member function createQueryBuilder() on null" at mypath/SerialNumberType.php line 20
```

Line 20 represents this part of the SerialNumberType.php:

```
$query = $this->em->createQueryBuilder();
```

I have no clue why this is happening. It's the same as in my other formbuilders.

Comment: Take a look at the `Controller` that uses the form which you copied. You should see that `em` is being passed there as an argument. If so, do the same in the other controller as well.

Comment: You need to declare your class and its requirements in the service container configuration

Comment: I found it thnx to you @Artamiel. I needed to send a value with the formbuilder request! If you make a answer for this question I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as I said in my comment, the `EntityManager` is injected into the form either from your `Controller` when the form is being initialized with `new MyForm()`. You can also use the third parameter `array $options = array()` to pass the entity manager, and it would be accessible in `buildForm`.

The manager could be also injected if the form is registered in your configuration file as a service, thus adding the service id in the `arguments` option.

So, there are many ways to pass the `EntityManager`, you just need to find out which is the one that suits you most. In your case, it should either be passed on initialization in your controller, or as an argument in your configuration file.